How to deploy a project written in next from json-server to vercel?
I have a project that I wrote in next js and used json-server for the fake backend. The problem is that I can't deploy the project to vercel because json-server doesn't start when building the project
I tried running multiple scripts at once using concurrently in verel, but that didn't work. Here is the command:
"scripts": {
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "json-server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000",
        "deploy": "concurrently \"npm run json-server\" \"npm run build && npm run start\"",
    },


I think you should create another endpoint to return fake backend because of NextJS can use as a backend service.

I don't really understand you.

I have posted my answer, can you check ? If you have any question, hope i can help you.

You can create another endpoint to return fake backend because of NextJS can use as a backend service.
Your API with NextJS
// pages/api/posts.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const posts = [
    { id: 1, title: "Post 1", content: "This is post 1" },
    { id: 2, title: "Post 2", content: "This is post 2" },
  ];
  res.status(200).json(posts);
}

Your component:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPosts(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <li key={post.id}>
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
            <p>{post.content}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}


When making a request, can I just specify fetch('/api/posts') without the domain or localhost?

Yes, that right

I can't send requests using axios. Here's the code:
const baseURL = '/api'
export const getRooms = () => axios.get('/rooms', { baseURL })
Next.Js throws an Invalid URL error. And when I go to the site along the path http://api/rooms all the data is displayed
I would be grateful if you help

You need an constant like this const SERVER_ENDPOINT = process.env.SERVER_ENDPOINT || "http://localhost:3000";
And use it with fetch: fetch(${SERVER_ENDPOINT}/api/posts)

SERVER_ENDPOINT is your NextJS endpoint

For local development, you can continue using json-server, but for production, use an actual API or one of the options above. To run both locally, you can use concurrently like this:


"scripts": {
  "dev": "concurrently \"next dev\" \"json-server --watch db.json --port 5000\"",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}




Yes, you're right, I'll do that
